# Using pandas to compute social distance between nodes from df on affiliations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe indicating the social distance between patents. I have already a dataframe showing the affiliation network of (co-)inventors and patents. The idea is to compute the minimum number of nodes (patents) connecting two patents based on the affiliated inventors. For example, the same inventor A is working on P1 and P2, so the distance should be 0. The distance between P3 and P1 would be 1 as A (P1) works with C on P2 and C works on P3. However, the distance should only be computed if the destination (kind) patent is younger than the source patent, e.g., the distance from P3 to P1 should not be included. inventor_id and patent_id are int values in the real dataset.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df_affiliation = pd.DataFrame({'inventor_id':['A','A','B','B','C','C','D'],
...                               'patent_id':['P1','P2','P1','P4','P2','P3','P3','P5'],
...                               'year':[1986,1987,1986,1989,1987,1988,1988]})
>>> df_affiliation
  inventor_id  patent_id  year
0           A         P1  1986
1           A         P2  1987
2           B         P1  1986
3           B         P4  1989
4           C         P2  1987
5           C         P3  1988
6           D         P3  1988
```

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
>>> df_distance = pd.DataFrame({'source_patent_id':['P1','P1','P1','P2','P2','P3'],
...                             'destination_patent_id':['P2','P3','P4','P3','P4','P4'],
...                             'distance':[0,1,0,0,1,2]})
>>> df_distance
  source_patent_id destination_patent_id  distance
0               P1                    P2         0
1               P1                    P3         1
2               P1                    P4         0
3               P2                    P3         0
4               P2                    P4         1
5               P3                    P4         2
```

To make the underlying social connection clearer, please find attached a representation by Singh (2005). Collaborative Networks as Determinants of Knowledge Diffusion Patterns [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCE8I.jpg).

Comment: How do we tell the difference between a source patent and a child patent?

Comment: You are also more likely to get an answer if you create a simpler version of your question with generalized column and group names and explain your problem directly in terms of the data instead of the reserach context we're not familiar with. Just for me I find it hard figuring out what's going on in the data while parsing the terminology and how it relates to the data format.

Comment: The distinction between source and child (destination) patent should be based on the year in df_affiliation. However, I have also a data set linking source and child patent but I thought it is computationally more feasible to create a df for the social distance and then take the respective value from there.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the calculation of your distance measure? To be specific, why is the distance between P3 and P4 = 2? I thought the idea was to count "internodes" of patents that have at least one inventor in common. However, P3 and P4 have no inventor in common.

Comment: @insulanus exactly, but P3 and P4 have co-inventors in common. The idea is to see if knowledge flows from P3 to P4 via the co-inventors. The picture I've attached shows this more clearly. P3 is shares the same inventor as P2 (1st node) and P2 shares an inventor with P1 (2nd node). P1 is then linked to P4 also via a common co-inventor. Thus, the inventor chain would be: C-A-B, and the resulting patent chain: P3-P2-P1-P4 (=> two nodes in between). I hope this makes it clearer :)